# Setar valor no scrolltop

Tags: javascript, extjs

Como que faço para setar um valor novo no scrolltop, ao invés de ele ser 0, ser por exemplo, um numero 'x'.

```
this.liveScroller.dom.scrollTop = 563;
```

Answer (score 0):

O método scrollTop funciona em todos navegadores modernos:

[Scroll Top](https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t35)

Exemplo:

**JavaScript**

Scroll Top da janela:

```
window.scrollY
```

Scroll Top de um elemento:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].scrollTop
```

**jQuery**

Scroll Top da janela:

```
jQuery(window).scrollTop();
```

Scroll Top de um elemento:

```
jQuery('#teste').scrollTop();
```

Comment: eu queria setar para o scrolltop começar com esse valor ao invés de 0